# SOAP API - How to set an email attribute?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, php

I'm creating an email via the SOAP API. So far, this is working:

```
// SOAP client
@$client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

// Login details
$client->username = 'xxx';
$client->password = 'xxx';

// Generate test email
$email = new ExactTarget_Email();
$email->Name = 'Test Email 1A';
$email->Subject = 'SUBJECT TBC';
$email->PreHeader = 'PREHEADER TBC';
$email->CharacterSet = 'utf-8';
$email->HTMLBody = '<p>Paragraph one</p>';
$email->EmailType = 'HTML';
$email->IsHTMLPaste = 'true';

$svEmail = new SoapVar($email, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'Email', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

$request = new ExactTarget_CreateRequest();
$request->Options = NULL;
$request->Objects = array($svEmail);

$results = $client->Create($request);
var_dump($results);
```

When creating an email via the UI, there is a field at the bottom "_AdditionalEmailAttribute1". How would I adapt the above code to assign a value to this attribute for the email I'm creating?

The documentation shows ways to create a new attribute, delete an attribute, or assign an attribute to a subscriber - but I haven't found out how to set a value for an existing attribute against an email.

From looking at what's available in the API, I was thinking it might be along the following lines:

```
$attribute = new ExactTarget_Attribute();
$attribute->Name('_AdditionalEmailAttribute1');
$attribute->Value('150801_ABC');

$svAttribute = new SoapVar($attribute, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'Attribute', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
$request->Objects = array($svEmail, $svAttribute);
```

with the last line replacing the similar line I have in the original code.

The ExactTarget_Attribute class has public properties called Name and Value, but when I attempt to use this code, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method ExactTarget_Attribute::Name() in exacttarget_test.php on line 40
```

I'm a bit cautious about experimenting with it too much, as I don't want to risk creating lots of new attributes unnecessarily.

How do you set the attribute values against an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a point of clarification, Additional Email Attributes are values that are automatically appended to all links in your email. They can be static text, personalization strings or AMPScript variables. **These are *not* Subscriber Profile Attributes.**

It appears there's a single `Additional` attribute can be set on an [EmailSendDefinition](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/emailsenddefinition/) object, not the [Email](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/email/) object.

So in the platform, you can set multiple `Additional Email Attribute` values when you create an email, but via API, you can only set a single attribute when creating an [User-Initiated Send](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_performing_and_deleting_email_send_definitions/) object.